# How to get all tags of a commit from the GitHub API

Tags: github-api

How do I get all the tags of a commit from the GitHub API.

Problem: I do have a file. I retrieved the commits of the file from the API. Now I need to know all the tags where a specific commit is included. The GitHub Website does list the tags nicely but I could not find a way on the API.

Comment: I'm looking for the same. I think the github API is just half baked.

Comment: Hey mate! I found the trick. You have to actually use the ref. Here it is an example: https://api.github.com/repos/wisebrains/wise-archetypes/tags

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat As far as I understand topicstarter he needs to find out all tags of a particular commit, not vice-versa. Moreover, commit which is present in the output of your url is the commit of the tag by itself

Answer (score 1):

In Github web UI, there is an internal call that retrieves the names of branches and tags associated to the given commit like this:

[image]

You can call this internal api and parse the tags in the html:

```
GET https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/branch_commits/{commit_sha}
```

example: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/branch_commits/28b768913b75752ecf9b6bb32766e27c241dbc46

Here is a [python](/questions/tagged/python) script that retrieves all tags for a specific commit using this workaround:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

owner = "mui-org"
repo = "material-ui"
commit_sha = "28b768913b75752ecf9b6bb32766e27c241dbc46"

r = requests.get(f"https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/branch_commits/{commit_sha}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
ul_list = soup.findAll("ul")

if len(ul_list) > 1:
    tag_ul = soup.findAll("ul")[1]
    tags = [ t.text for t in tag_ul.findAll("li") if t.text != "…"]
    print(tags)
```

[try this on repl.it](https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/GithubGetTagsForCommit)

This is also super fast, for example, the following code retrieves the 1255 tags (at this time) associated with this commit:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

owner = "aosp-mirror"
repo = "platform_manifest"
commit_sha = "d8bad7851a80605389de1611638c2717242db2b4"

r = requests.get(f"https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/branch_commits/{commit_sha}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
ul_list = soup.findAll("ul")

if len(ul_list) > 1:
    tag_ul = soup.findAll("ul")[1]
    tags = [ t.text for t in tag_ul.findAll("li") if t.text != "…"]
    print(tags)
    print(len(tags))
```

#### Downsides

- This won't work for private repositories since you would need web authentication for that
- It fails to use the official API

Answer (score -5):

It seems that github secretly provides a such API The url is as follows: `https://api.github.com/repos/{{user}}/{{repository}}/tags`
I guess it works for any ref ( notes etc ).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I understand. First, it is not secret, but [well documented](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags). Second, this lists all tags; OP wants to only list tags that include specific commit.