# GitHub GraphQL API: Get tags for a commit

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-api-v4

I don't know if it's just hard to form a useful search for this problem or if there is no solution, but I've been trying to figure out how to use the GitHub GraphQL API to fetch all tags associated with a given commit.

I'm new to GraphQL and the GitHub API, so I'm just using [GitHub's explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) to try to find the mechanism to do this.

Here's what I've tried, where there is a commit with hash `bfa0635104bc9a559254b5007646942ff269ae11` and message `1.0.0`, tagged with `v1.0.0`. I'm trying to get that tag, given the commit hash.

```
{
  repository(owner: "bscotch", name: "stitch") {
    createdAt
    description
    name
    object(expression: "bfa0635104bc9a559254b5007646942ff269ae11") {
      ... on Commit {
        message
        oid
      }
      ... on Tag {
        tagId: id
        target {
          oid
        }
      }
    }
    ref(qualifiedName: "bfa0635104bc9a559254b5007646942ff269ae11") {
      name
    }
    refs(first: 10, refPrefix: "refs/tags/", orderBy: {field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE, direction: DESC}, query: "bfa0635104bc9a559254b5007646942ff269ae11") {
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output of the above only returns data for the `... on Commit` content. Everything else is completely absent:

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "createdAt": "2020-09-18T18:47:33Z",
      "description": "A Gamemaker Studio 2 Pipeline Development Kit. A CLI and Node.JS API for creating GMS2 asset pipelines.",
      "name": "stitch",
      "object": {
        "message": "1.0.0",
        "oid": "bfa0635104bc9a559254b5007646942ff269ae11"
      },
      "ref": null,
      "refs": {
        "nodes": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this via the API? My best guess is that, if there is, it's via the `refs` field.

Comment: Seriously, it's _really_ hard to find the answer to this. I don't think it's possible, which seems pretty weird. I've been banging my head against the wall trying to manipulate their GraphQL explorer to make it work to no avail. Sorry :(

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259477/how-to-get-all-tags-of-a-commit-from-the-github-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also been struggling and this isn't the best answer, but it at least works at minimum.

Query `refs/tags/` to get all tags, then filter manually in whatever language you're using for the matching OID. You're not guaranteed to fetch *all* the tags in one call so that you for sure have the OID in it, but I was trying to match against what was likely a recent tag, so it worked fine.

```
{
  repository(name: "dg", owner: "dgattey") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", last: 100) {
      nodes {
        name
        target {
          oid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gets me a giant list, but in it, I have

```
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "v2.0.1",
            "target": {
              "oid": "85fe69df20062aafeea7593c45c1785f44208252"
            }
          }
        }
```

And I can use other code to check "85fe69df20062aafeea7593c45c1785f44208252" against the OID I was searching for. Not ideal!

Comment: This is basically what I did. One of those things that felt like it should be easy... I used to be on BitBucket, and this was something I could do via their API.

Comment: Yea I'm shocked that Github, for how good most of their API is, sucks when it comes to tags & releases